# possible to mark all mail as read using one line terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, email, postfix

I am not trying to remove all the mails.

I googled for mark all mail as read, actually got posts saying how to delete them instead.

I found out using `echo p | mail` will output first of unread then mark it read, but if I do this, I have to loop through them.

I figured for all read mails, they will be appended to a file named `mbox`

What I am trying to do is...I want to create a `bash` file which is then used for `crontab` that let's say, at the end of each month, change the name of `mbox` into `month-year` in this way I can keep track and organize the mails BUT in order to have the mails appended into `mbox` is reading the mails one by one first.

Am I thinking this in a wrong direction? Or can someone give me some advices?

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT: I am just using `sudo apt install mailutils` for my ubuntu server

Comment: @dessert edited, that's the only thing I installed

Comment: You have to find or modify a script , example - http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2009-01-11-markallread.php . Please read the comments in the script and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Panther thx thx, I will give that a try soon :D thx thx for the reference t hough ^_^

Answer (score 17):

I was able to do it as follows:

1. Type `mail`, it tell me how many unread messages I have. Let's say, 31.
2. Type `t 1-31`, it displays all messages from 1 to 31 in a big concatenated sheet (*turned out that `t *` achieves the same result, thanks to [Jaime Hablutzel](https://askubuntu.com/users/18014/jaime-hablutzel)*)
3. Type `q` to quit view mode, type `q` again to quit `mail`

That's it! `mail` says all 31 messages saved in your `mbox` file, and next time you enter it, it will say "no mail for you".

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This works perfectly on the macOS mail utility as well

Comment: Isn't `t *` more straightforward?.

Comment: It is :) I just didn't know of this possibility - thanks for the hint!

Comment: In my case I wanted to _delete_ all the mail messages. For this, all you need to do is: 1) type `mail`; 2) `d *`; 3) `q`

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04. When I press `q`, it shows the next message. When I press `Ctrl`+`C` and then `q`, it marks as read only few messages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've solved it by making a text consisting only of many `q` letters and pasting it into the message display of `mail`

Comment: if you still want to see your mail ever again, then you should follow that up with `hold *` and then `q` if you want to exit without shoving the mail off into the (home folder) void, then `x` and it will not persist any changes like which emails you've viewed

Answer (score 2):

A minor improvement on Vlad's answer. If you are not interested in the content and just want to mark the mails read, the follow command is more efficient: `top :u`. The command "top" shows only the first few lines of the message and :u gives just unread messages.

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail) for mail:

> #### **seen**
>
> Takes a message list and marks all messages as having been read.

Therefore in mail;

```
? seen *
```

will mark all messages read without removing them.

Although it appears ubuntu mail doesn't have this command.